# NoReverseMatch at /admin/...(adding custom user with id as char field).. Unable to create user with a Custom User Model in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am working on a legacy database from .net application and in the users table the id field is of char type and is something like this-- 99124-b8f3-4d92-a0b1-763cc1f10f1b. So, I have taken char field on id. creating super user on shell is working fine and updating/changing existing user is working. How ever, when I try creating a user with User Creation form.. I get the below error.
[image]

My code is as follows:

## Models.Py

```
def generate_id(hash_length):
    hashtext = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=hash_length))
    prefix='kcov'
    return f"{prefix}_{hashtext}"


gender_choices= ((0, 'Female'), (1, 'Male'))

class Aspnetusers(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True,db_column='Email')
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=128, db_column='Id', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=100, unique=False
    #### few more fields ###

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'AspNetUsers'
        verbose_name='User'
        verbose_name_plural='Users'

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
       if not self.id:
           prefix = 'KC{}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y%m%d'))
           prev_instances = self.__class__.objects.filter(id__contains=prefix)
           if prev_instances.exists():
              last_instance_id = prev_instances.last().special_id[-4:]
              self.special_id = prefix+'{0:04d}'.format(int(last_instance_id)+1)
           else:
               self.special_id = prefix+'{0:04d}'.format(1)
       super(Aspnetusers, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_superuser

    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return self.is_superuser

    def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse('Aspnetusers', kwargs={
            'id': self.id,
        })
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name
```

## Managers.py

```
class UserManager(auth_models.BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

## Forms.py

```
class UCForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': "The two password fields didn't match.",}

    email= forms.EmailField(max_length=50, help_text="Required")   
  
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password confirmation",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text="Enter the same password as above, for verification."
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Aspnetusers
        fields = ('email','username', 'password1','password2')

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UCForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email= self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save(using= self._db)
        return user



class UserLimitedChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Aspnetusers
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','username')


class PasswordResetRequestForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(label="Email", max_length=254)



class UserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Aspnetusers
        fields='__all__'
```

## admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(auth_admin.UserAdmin):
   
    # fieldsets = (
    #     (None, {'fields': ('email','username','password')}),
    #     ('Personal info', {'fields': (('first_name', 'last_name','dateofbirth','gender','photo'),('address','mobile','city','country','state'), ('phonenumber','phonenumberconfirmed'),
    #     )}),
    #     ('Other Info',{'fields':(('parentuser',('assignedto','assignedcountries'),('company','countrycode')))}),
    #     ('Tags Info',{'fields':('usertags','usertaggroups')}),
    #     ('Others',{'fields':('emailconfirmed','isconfirmemailsent','notificationemails','receivenotifications','lockenddate','lockenabled','lockoutenddateutc','lockoutenabled','twofactorenabled', 'isshowcomssion','securitystamp')}),
    #     ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',)}),
    #                                 )
    limited_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email','username')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email','username', 'password1', 'password2')
        }),
    )
    form = UserChangeForm
    limited_form = UserLimitedChangeForm
    add_form = UCForm
    change_password_form = auth_admin.AdminPasswordChangeForm
    list_display = ('Edit','Delete','email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_superuser')
    list_display_links = ('email',)
    exclude= ('accessfailedcount','last_login','signalrconnid','createdon','updatedon','createdby')
    show_full_result_count = False
    list_filter = ('email',)
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    ordering = ('email',)
    empty_value_display = '-- NA --'

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(pk=request.user.pk)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        defaults = {}
        if obj and not request.user.is_superuser:
            defaults.update({
                'form': self.limited_form,
                'fields': admin.util.flatten_fieldsets(self.limited_fieldsets),
            })
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **defaults)

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and not request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.limited_fieldsets
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

admin.site.register(Aspnetusers,UserAdmin)
```

Comment: I don't see you setting the `id` field. You only set some `special_id` field?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I didn't understand your comment.. I am taking id as CharField instead of django's default Autofield

Comment: You need to set the id somehow when an instance is saved, I don't see you setting the id...

Comment: Yes Abdul.. with the current save method that I have the Id field is null in db, but when i try UUID field ,  badly formed hexadecimal UUID string is the error #  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, db_column='Id', unique=True,default=uuid.uuid4, editable= False)  # Field name made lowercase.